# Resolved- Sage Error Cannot Open Company File a Required Data File is Missing

Tags: business-process-management

### What is the Sage Error Cannot Open Company File?

The Sage Error Cannot Open Company File occurs when the software is unable to locate a required data file, resulting in an inability to open the company file. This error can be caused by various reasons such as corrupted or damaged files, incorrect permissions, network issues and more.  Another cause could be insufficient user permissions. You need adequate privileges on your computer system and server to access all necessary folders and files associated with Sage accounting software. Read More-: [Sage 50 won’t open after the Update](https://www.accountingadvice.co/sage-50-wont-open-after-the-update/)